# Apply previous filters when action filter is released

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 sheets. one sheet has line chart of month( on x axis) vs TRP (on y axis). Other sheet with month and hour vs TRP line chart. On my 2nd worksheet I want filter which shows hourly distribution for only recent 2 months. Have created action filter from 1st sheet. if I click on month it will take me to 2nd sheet and will show hourly distribution for that clicked month. But when I release action filter I want my second sheet to go back to previous filter which  is recent 2 months display.

Thanks!

[1st sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx0OB.png) ,

[2nd sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwATI.png) ,

[when I release action filter I want my 2nd sheet like this, Hourly distribution for recent 2 months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5683.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the filter or edit an action filter, there is an option to choose whether you want the action to remain after clearing the selection or you want it to show the visual before action was applied on it.

You will find the 3 options(**Clearing the selection will**) near edit action filters-> Target sheet, namely:
 1. Leave the filter
 2. Show all values
 3. Exclude all values

For your purpose, you should **choose 2nd option** i.e. **Show all values**

Comment: Thank you for help. This case will show all values on my 2nd sheet, but I want only 2 months data to be shown on 2nd sheet.

Comment: @MatXavier it should automatically show the sheet that was created. If the filter is present on the target sheet for 2 months data. It will show visual only for 2 months.

Comment: But if the filter on 2nd sheet is present for say month 11 and 12, and if action filter I click for is of month 4 then it will show blank for actions.